# How can I make my number guessing game take multiple inputs?

Tags: python

After the first input, I run into the error saying the next variable is not defined. I'm sure it's an easy fix I'm overlooking but I can't seem to find a solid workaround online.

Comment: There is no `next` variable in the code. Also your code is executed only once, do you want that user should keep guessing until the right ones is guessed?

Comment: For a game like this you want to allow the player to keep guessing until they get it. But you don't know how long that could be. For that sort of situation use a while loop. If this was a hangman sort of game (only so many wrong guesses till they lose) you would use some sort of counter. Also, one more thing to set you on the path. If the person says the computer's guess is too low, should the computer keep using a random number?

Comment: by "next" i mean if the computer guesses 10 and I'm thinking of 15, I will put "l" to indicate that the guess was too low. The computer will then output a higher number, but the next thing i input gives me an error saying name "whatever input" is not defined. Also, yes the user should keep giving inputs until the computer guesses the right one. Appreciate the help!

Comment: You state "I'm trying to make a program in python", but without showing any of your attempts or demonstrating other own effort your post is only a list of requirements for a desired program. In that it does not match the minimum requirements for a question on StackOverflow and risks negative feedback. Because of that I undo your most recent edit, which  removed exactly what made your post a better one. Please see [ask] and take the [tour] for some background on this. Also helpful: [mre].

Answer (score -1):

The goal is to de-increment and increment between the highest - 1 and lowest + 1 in a loop and enter these values into the computer's guess.

```
import random

print("Think of a number in your head and the computer will try to guess it!")

print("Once you see the guess, you can tell the computer if the guess was too high, too low, or correct.")

highest = 20
lowest = 1
while True:
    guess = random.randint(lowest, highest)
    print("The computer guesses: " + str(guess))
    print("Enter 'h' if the guess was too high.")
    print("Enter 'l' if the guess was too low.")
    print("Enter 'c' if the guess was correct.")
    response = input()
    if response == "h":
        print("Too high")
        highest = guess - 1
    elif response == "l":
        print("Too low")
        lowest = guess + 1
    elif response == "c":
        print("Nice work!")
        break
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a similar method to the other questions which uses the `if __name__ == "__main__"` you'll commonly see.

```py
import random
import sys

# There is now a random number between 1 and 20 stored in guess.
GUESS = random.randint(1, 20)


def play_game():
    print("The computer guesses: " + str(GUESS))
    while True:
        response = input()
        if response == "h":
            print("The computer guesses: " + str(random.randint(1, GUESS)))
        elif response == "l":
            print("The computer guesses: " + str(random.randint(GUESS, 20)))
        elif response == "c":
            print("Nice work!")
            sys.exit(0)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(
        """Think of a number in your head and the computer will try to guess it!\nOnce you see the guess, you can tell the computer if the guess was too high, too low, or correct."""
    )
    play_game()
```

Answer (score -1):

I dont see any code or proper explanation of what you want, but from what I gather from comments and other answers, I think this is what you want

```
import random

hl = 20
ll = 1

print("Welcome to guessing game")
print("Pick a number between",ll,"and",hl)
randint = 0
while True:
  randint = random.randint(ll,hl)
  inp = input("Is your number "+str(randint)+" ? H for high, L for low, C for correct\n").lower()
  if inp.startswith("h"):
    hl = randint
  elif inp.startswith("l"):
    ll = randint
  else :
    break
print("Your number is",inp)
```